Sanitize form in AntDesign
I have the values of a form saved as {"title": "test"}. However, I have updated the structure of the form such that it now saves as {"title": {"en": "test"}}.
Unfortunately AntDesign still injects the previous version of the data into the form and when I save it now comes out as:
{"title": {"0": "t", "1": "e", "2": "s", "3": "t", "en": "test}}.
Is there a way where I can only get the form values as they currently are?

Please provide the code how you set the form values
